# Factoring $−x^{3}−3x^{2}+4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have this polynomial:

$$−x^{3}−3x^{2}+4$$

and I know it factors to this:

$$−(x−1)(x+2)(x+2)$$

But how do I do this formally and in a step by step way?

Comment: So you were assigned this polynomial to factor, and the text's solution is $-(x-1)(x+2)^2$.  And what have you done?  In what course of level did you encounter this problem statement?  What confuses you?

Comment: $−x^{3}−3x^{2}+4 = -(x^3+3x^2 -4)$, to start.

Comment: In general, this requires a somewhat cumbersome cubic formula, but for cases like this, the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) is your friend.

Comment: Check for rational roots.  $1$ is a root so $x-1$ is a factor.  $-2$ is a root so $x+2$ is a a factor.  Use synthetic division and $-x^3-3x^2 + 4= -x^2(x-1)-4x(x-1)+4(x-1)=(x-1)(-x^2-4x+4)$.  And if we use synthetic division $-x^2+4x +4 = -x(x+2) -2(x+2)=(x+2)(-x-2)$.  So the full factor is $(x-1)(x+2)(-x-2)=-(x-1)(x+2)(x+2)$.

Comment: @fleablood  This should be an answer.  It would be the best one since the OP wants "systematic."

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $f(x) = -x^{3} - 3x^{2} + 4$. Then notice the sum of its coefficients equals zero. This means that $f(1) = 0$.

Now you can factor $x - 1$ out, whence you are going to obtain a second degree polynomial.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Note
$$−x^{3}−3x^{2}+4= −x^{3}+x^2 - 4x^{2}+4
= −x^{2}(x-1)- 4(x^{2}-1)\\
= -(x-1)(x^2+4x+4)=-(x-1)(x+2)^2
$$

Comment: How did you get from $-x^2(x-1)-4(x^2-1)$ to the next step?

Comment: @Jwan622 - note $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$. so $x-1$ is the common factor.